# How to use File Chooser in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jfilechooser

My Java code below is trying to import a photo to place on `new JLabel(new ImageIcon(""));` using File Chooser. I have no experience with file Chooser but **I want to select a image and then have the image place on the jLabel.** I don't know what to put in `action event e` that will help me achieve this goal.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class back extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public int act = 0;


public back(){
    setTitle("Question");
    JPanel Panel1 = new JPanel();
    Panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel Panel2 = new JPanel();
    Panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));


    JLabel myButton1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(""));

    JButton myButton2 = new JButton("2:Select Image");



    myButton2.addActionListener(this);


    Panel2.add(myButton1);
    Panel2.add(myButton2);


    Panel1.add(Panel2,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(Panel1);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500, 500);

    setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     SomeImageType image = findImage();
                                  displayImage(image, Panel1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new back();
}
}
```

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.  ...

Comment: 4) **See [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).** Get back to us if you need to, with an attempt at implementing the examples in the tutorial, into your own code. Voting to close.